# What does the `test` instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking at some small assembler codes and I'm having trouble understanding the TEST instruction and its use. I'm looking at the following code at the end of a loop:

```
8048531:    84 c0                   test   al,al
8048533:    75 dc                   jne    8048511 <function+0x2d>
```

The way i understand TEST is that it works a bit like the AND operator and it sets some flags. I guess I don't really understand how the flags work. `test al,al` to me looks like it checks the same lower bits and will always get the same results.

Can someone explain?

Comment: @Evan: Please to *not* create more tags for specific x86 instructions.  We can discuss this on meta if you want, but don't tag more questions until after discussion.

Comment: @PeterCordes https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366109/124486

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It tests the register against itself, just to set the flags. The result will be different for a zero and a non-zero value.

Comment: So to clarify, when does the TEST produce a result that will make the JNE jump?

Comment: It sets ZF if the tested register is zero, otherwise it clears the flag. The JNE jumps (or not) depending on that flag.

Comment: @danielhc: The JNE instruction is also known as JNZ - "Jump if Not Zero". In your case, the jump will be taken if the register al is not zero.