# The point of test %eax %eax

Tags: assembly, x86, att

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x86 Assembly - ‘testl’ eax against eax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/x86-assembly-testl-eax-against-eax)

I'm very very new to assembly language programming, and I'm currently trying to read the assembly language generated from a binary.  I've run across

```
 test   %eax,%eax
```

or `test %rdi, %rdi`, etc. etc. I'm very confused as to what this does.  Isn't the values in `%eax, %eax` the same?  What is it testing?  I read somewhere that it is doing the `AND` operation.....but since they are the same value, wouldn't it just return `%eax`?

The following is just one instance where I found this usage:

```
   400e6e:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   400e70:       74 05                   je     400e77 <phase_1+0x23>
```

I thought `je` jumps if the two values being compared are equal......well, because  `%eax` is well, itself, in what situation would we NOT jump?

I'm a beginner to programming in general, so I'd appreciate it very much if someone could explain this to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Since some answers seem a little bit unclear about it, let me point out that `TEST` updates other flags apart from `ZF` as well. See the instruction set reference.

Comment: @Jester fixed (in my answer), sorry.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [What does the `test` instruction do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6002079)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

`CMP` subtracts the operands and sets the flags. Namely, it sets the zero flag if the difference is zero (operands are equal).

`TEST` sets the zero flag, `ZF`, when the result of the AND operation is zero. If two operands are equal, their bitwise AND is zero when both are zero. `TEST` also sets the sign flag, `SF`, when the most significant bit is set in the result, and the parity flag, `PF`, when the number of set bits is even.

`JE` [Jump if Equals] tests the zero flag and jumps if the flag is set. `JE` is an alias of `JZ` [Jump if Zero] so the disassembler cannot select one based on the opcode. `JE` is named such because the zero flag is set if the arguments to `CMP` are equal.

So,

```
TEST %eax, %eax
JE   400e77 <phase_1+0x23>
```

jumps if the `%eax` is zero.

Comment: where can I find information like this?

Comment: namely? The list of x86 instructions [is on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), which also links a [spec by Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) as well as [another (quite readable) reference on wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100407092131/http://home.comcast.net/~fbui/intel.html). [A tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly) is also available on Wikibooks.

Comment: yes, this is the information I was looking for

Comment: Jumps if `%eax` is zero, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow

Comment: `If two operands are equal, their bitwise AND is zero when both are zero.` therefore `AND`ing 2 numbers is useful only when both are 0, which will be the case in 1:100000 cases, that's pretty useless. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 65):

Some x86 instructions are designed to leave the content of the operands (registers) as they are and just set/unset specific internal CPU flags like the zero-flag (ZF). You can think at the ZF as a true/false boolean flag that resides inside the CPU.


in this particular case, TEST instruction performs a bitwise logical AND, discards the actual result and sets/unsets the ZF according to the result of the logical and: if the result is zero it sets ZF = 1, otherwise it sets ZF = 0.


Conditional jump instructions like JE are designed to look at the ZF for jumping/notjumping so using TEST and JE together is equivalent to perform a conditional jump based on the value of a specific register:


example:

```
TEST EAX,EAX
JE some_address
```

the CPU will jump to "some_address" if and only if ZF = 1, in other words if and only if AND(EAX,EAX) = 0 which in turn it can occur if and only if EAX == 0


the equivalent C code is:

```
if(eax == 0)
{
    goto some_address
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This checks if `EAX` is zero. The instruction `test` does bitwise `AND` between the arguments, and if `EAX` contains zero, the result sets the ZF, or ZeroFlag.

Comment: This is the standard way to do it. One could also do cmp %eax, 0 (immediate) for "clarity to beginners" but that would encode to a longer instruction (aka less efficient).

Answer (score 5):

`test` is a non-destructive `and`, it doesn't return the result of the operation but it sets the flags register accordingly. To know what it really tests for you need to check the following instruction(s). Often out is used to check a register against 0, possibly coupled with a `jz` conditional jump.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, that `test` "and"s the two operands. But the result is discarded, the only thing that stays, and thats the important part, are the flags. They are set and thats the reason why the `test` instruction is used (and exist).

`JE` jumps not when equal (it has the meaning when the instruction before was a comparison), what it really does, it jumps when the `ZF` flag is set. And as it is one of the flags that is set by `test`, this instruction sequence (test x,x; je...) has the meaning that it is jumped when x is 0.

For questions like this (and for more details) I can just recommend a book about x86 instruction, e.g. even when it is really big, the Intel documentation is very good and precise.