# NASM module to convert hex into string and print it out. Assembles but not working as expected

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I am trying to write a simple assembly code to spit out hex values to the screen. There are two files `print_screen.asm` which is working with other modules. I think the problem is in my logic when trying to convert hex to string. My code is:

```
[org 0x7c00]

xor dx,dx
xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx

mov dx, 0x1fb6

call print_hex

jmp endi;

print_hex:
    pusha

    mov ax,0x0001
    and ax,dx
    add ah,48
    mov byte [HEX_OUT+5],ah

    mov ax,0x0010
    and ax,dx
    add ah,48
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 4],ah

    mov ax,0x0100
    and ax,dx
    add ah,48
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 3],ah

    mov ax,0x1000
    and ax,dx
    add ah,48
    mov byte [HEX_OUT + 2],ah

    mov bx,HEX_OUT
    call print_string

    popa
    ret

jmp endi

%include "print_string.asm"

endi:
;data
HEX_OUT: db '0x0000',0

SAMPLE: db 'a',0
times 510 - ($-$$) db  0
dw 0xaa55
```

`print_screen.asm` (working with other modules):

```
 print_string:
    pusha
    cld
    mov ah,0x0e

config: mov al,[bx]
    ;Comparing the strings
    cmp byte [bx],0x00  ;Comparing for null
    jne print
    je end

print:  int 0x10
    add bx,1
    jmp config

end:    popa
    ret
```

Comment: You are only masking out 1 bit at a time instead of 4. Also, you leave it in place.

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `mov ax,0x0010; and ax,dx`? Put in some value for an example, and see what comes out.

Comment: @Jester i gotta use F. Dang stupid me. Thanks a lot. And infact keep shifting those values too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jester is it possible for me to use a loop?? If possible how do i add offset to the HEX_OUT label.

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop. You can do something like `[HEX_OUT+bx]`.

Comment: Related: See [How to convert a number to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) for efficient code for a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov ax,0x0001
> and ax,dx
> add ah,48
> mov byte [HEX_OUT+5],ah
> ```

In the above snippet you only keep a single bit where you need to keep 4 bits.
You also do an addition on `AH` when the result definitely is in `AL`.
Because of how the ASCII set is organized, you can't just merily add 48 to convert into the hexadecimal. There is a gap between the encoding for '9' (57) and the encoding for 'A' (65). Your code needs to account for this!

For the least significant hex digit:

```
    mov ax, dx     ;Original number
    and al, 15     ;Keep 4 bits
    add al, '0'    ;Make text
    cmp al, '9'
    jbe .LessA     ;Already fine for '0' to '9'
    add al, 7      ;Bridge the gap to reach 'A' to 'F'
.LessA:
    mov [HEX_OUT + 5], al
```

For the next hexdigit this would become:

```
    mov ax, dx     ;Original number
    shr ax, 4
    and al, 15     ;Keep 4 bits
    add al, '0'    ;Make text
    cmp al, '9'
    jbe .LessA     ;Already fine for '0' to '9'
    add al, 7      ;Bridge the gap to reach 'A' to 'F'
.LessA:
    mov [HEX_OUT + 4], al
```

For the next hexdigit this would become:

```
    mov ax, dx     ;Original number
    shr ax, 8
    and al, 15     ;Keep 4 bits
    add al, '0'    ;Make text
    cmp al, '9'
    jbe .LessA     ;Already fine for '0' to '9'
    add al, 7      ;Bridge the gap to reach 'A' to 'F'
.LessA:
    mov [HEX_OUT + 3], al
```

For the next hexdigit this would become:

```
    mov ax, dx     ;Original number
    shr ax, 12
    and al, 15     ;Keep 4 bits
    add al, '0'    ;Make text
    cmp al, '9'
    jbe .LessA     ;Already fine for '0' to '9'
    add al, 7      ;Bridge the gap to reach 'A' to 'F'
.LessA:
    mov [HEX_OUT + 2], al
```

---

This rapidly got longer than is good for us, so using a **loop** will be much better.
Next solution will start from the high end but the end result will be no different.

```
    mov bx, 2      ;Position for most significant digit
.Next:
    ror dx, 4      ;Bring digit in lowest 4 bits
    mov al, dl     ;Copy number
    and al, 15     ;Keep 4 bits
    add al, '0'    ;Make text
    cmp al, '9'
    jbe .LessA     ;Already fine for '0' to '9'
    add al, 7      ;Bridge the gap to reach 'A' to 'F'
.LessA:
    mov [HEX_OUT + bx], al
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 6      ;Did we fill chars at +2 +3 +4 +5 ?
    jb  .Next      ;Not yet
```

Because there are 4 iterations in this loop and the number in `DX` is rotated 4x each time, `DX` will hold the original value in the end. No need to preserve it.

---

> ```
> jmp endi;
> ```

What's this supposed to achieve? This is jumping to *data* and that's certainly not executable code! If you want an endless loop then simply write:

```
jmp $
```

---

The other file, that you say is working with other modules, is a mess!!
Everybody keeps neglecting this, but the BIOS teletype function requires the `BH` register to have the desired display page. Therefore it's always a bad idea to use `BX` as the string pointer.
Here's a good solution that doesn't require you to change all of your existing code (concerning the use of `BX`):

```
print_string:
    pusha
    mov     si, bx
    mov     bh, 0      ;Display page 0
    ;mov     bl, 7      ;Color if this were a graphical screen
    cld                ;Required to use LODSB correctly
    jmp     .start
  .write:
    mov     ah, 0x0E   ;BIOS.Teletype
    int     0x10
  .start:
    lodsb              ;Increments the pointer automatically
    cmp     al, 0      ;Comparing for null
    jne     .write
    popa
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

There's code on the Russian side of Stack Overflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924141/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-int-13h-bios for conversion of hex byte to string that's cleaner. Here's the snippet:

```
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, ah
shr bl, 0x04
mov al, [bx+hex_nums]
mov [error_code_hex], al
and ah, 0x0F
mov bl, ah
mov ah, [bx+hex_nums]
mov [error_code_hex+1], ah
hex_nums: db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

error_code_hex is where it prints the hex character. It basically takes the 4 bit as a sequence to reference the bytes of the ASCII hex sequence. Has anyone made this work?

Comment: `and al, 0xF0` is redundant before `shr al, 4`.  The bits masked away are about to be shifted out.  It's also pointless to use AL instead of doing `mov bl, ah` / `shr bl, 4`, saving the `mov bl,al` instruction.

Comment: That's better.  What do you mean "Has anyone made this work?"  Are you trying to ask a new question?  Looks totally normal for converting AH to a 2-digit hex string.  Except that `hex_nums:` can't be in-line with the code, or those 16 bytes will be decoded as instructions!.  You need to put the lookup table in its own section, or after your other code.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can have it in code section if you do jump before.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: Yes, of course, but there's [little to no benefit to mixing code and data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609077/224132) on x86, just the downside of having to `jmp` over it.  Which this code doesn't do.  I did mention the "after your other code" alternative to another section.

Comment: Related: [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756)

Comment: @PeterCordes if you have .data at all. say in bootloaders you don't